# Expected Value Word Problem -Roulette Wheel

Tags: probability

The probability a roulette wheel stops on a red number is 18/37.
If it lands on red and you bet red, then you receive double you bet (including your bet).

If you bet $1 on 10 consecutive plays, what is the probability that you make a profit?

My answer:

To make a profit, you need 5 wins and 5 loses.
Let X be the number of wins, X ~ Binomial(10, 18/37).

$$\Bbb P(5) = \binom{10}{5}(18/37)^5(19/37)^{5}$$

I found this to be equal to .245 which I have been told is incorrect.
I can't find any flaw in my thinking, any clue would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find P(X > 5), not P(X = 5).